# Unable to write a file in QSPI as USB Mass Storage

Tags: arduino

I'm using an Arduino GIGA Wifi.
I have create a partition for using QSPI as USB Mass Storage.
I can read file, I can list directory and I can also write a file in the setup() method:

```
  mbed::BlockDevice *raw_qspi = mbed::BlockDevice::get_default_instance();
  mbed::FATFileSystem ota("ota");
  mbed::MBRBlockDevice ota_data(raw_qspi, 2);
  ota.mount(&ota_data);

  FILE *f = fopen("/ota/settings.txt", "w");
  fprintf(f, "%d\n", 0);
  fprintf(f, "%d\n", 0);
  fprintf(f, "%d\n", 1500);
  fprintf(f, "%d\n", 0);
  fprintf(f, "%d\n", 1);
  fprintf(f, "%d\n", 0);
  fprintf(f, "%s\n", machineId);
  fflush(f);
  fclose(f);
  writeLcd("ACME");
```

What happen is that when someone push a button I want to write again all the data above, but as soon as I run the same code above, a part the initiation of the mbed,  the Arduino GIGA crashes (blink red led).
Of course this happen inside the loop function which I think it is where the problem lays.